# How to enumerate shapeless Record and access field keys in runtime?

Tags: scala, record, shapeless

I am writing generic code for processing lists of case class instances, 
collecting values in each field, combining and then passing it to the library.

Using shapeless `LabelledGeneric` and polymorphic functions, it looks like this:

```
object toNamedSingletonListOfValues extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseField[K,T] = 
    at[FieldType[K, T]](field => { field.key -> List[T](field) })
}

val generic = LabelledGeneric[MyClass]
val records = listOfMyClassInstances.map(generic.to)
val values = records.map(_.map(toNamedSingletonListOfValues)) // Then combining and passing
```

However, I need a way of getting `field.key` because the library needs the parameter names.

Would you mind suggesting the solution?

Answer (score 12):

You can access the key (which is known at compile-time) as a runtime value through an instance of the `Witness` type class:

```
object toNamedSingletonListOfValues extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseField[K, T](implicit wk: Witness.Aux[K]) = 
    at[FieldType[K, T]](field => { wk.value -> List[T](field) })
}
```

No need for runtime reflection!

Comment: Thank you! I have some things more to rewrite now, but it actually allowed progress for me. BTW, I was trying to use Aux'es, however, I could not figure out Aux from what object I need to use. No docs for the Aux'es, and it is almost impossible to infer this knowledge from the shapeless source code, as Aux definitions are scattered across all the shapeless source code files.

Comment: The `Aux` types are all paired with a specific type class and are designed to promote a type member to a type parameter. You could write this with `wk: Witness { type T = K }`, but the `Aux` version is nicer.

Answer (score 1):

Found dirty hack is to make Poly look like:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object toNamedSingletonListOfValues extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseField[K: TypeTag, T] = at[FieldType[K, T]] { field =>
    (typeOf[K] match { case TypeRef(_, _, args) => args }).last.toString.drop("java.lang.String(\"".size).dropRight(2) -> List[T]()
  }
}
```

Is there a nicer solution around?